# PancakeSwap API - how to get APR?

Tags: cryptocurrency, cryptoapi, pancakeswap

I need info about pools **APR/APY** from API endpoints like:
https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/summary
or
https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/pairs
but this info is missed there.
**How can I get it ?**

When going to v3 API, eg . https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v3/pairs
I get the response:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

**How to solve that ?**

The pancakeswap api page: https://syncwith.com/api/pancakeswap
It **does not have reference to v3 api though**.

### Calculating APR based on Volume 24h and Liquidity

I've found the way to [calculate APR based on volume24 and liquidity](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/products/yield-farming#calculating-lp-reward-apr). Yet as I try to calculate APR  with the current values, i get the wrong APR*:

```
  Token            Volume          APR       Liquidity
 WBNB+BUSD        174278887       23.15      467090610
  USDT+WBNB        227057          0.06       241228503
 USDT+BUSD        28411575        5.15       342070717
  ETH+WBNB         38904           0.02       104583785
 Cake+WBNB        37343           0.01       286549465
```

Compare it with those at the [website for pools/pairs](https://pancakeswap.finance/info/pools):

[image]

**What's wrong here ?**